# Находим нужные элементы BeautifulSoap

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.myscore.ru/football/england/premier-league/').content

soap = BeautifulSoup(page)
test1 = soap.findAll('tr', class = 'stage-finished')
```

Нужно найти тег `tr` с классом `stage-finished`. Не могу найти нормальный метод, для нахождения.

Comment: А он там есть?)

Comment: Распечатайте page и посмотрите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.myscore.ru/football/england/premier- 
     league/').content

soap = BeautifulSoup(page)

tr = soap.findAll('tr', {'class' : 'stage-finished'}, limit=None)
print(soap)
print(tr.text)
print(tr.text)
```